# Is android letting apps know I'm using VPN?

Tags: connection-issues, vpn

I'm abroad and trying to use my Norwegian app using a VPN, but somehow it knows I'm connecting though VPN and denying me to stream. (It's giving  a specific exception giving this exact information.)

Is it actually possible for the coders to use a function to let the app check this, or is it because the IP is a known VPN IP?

Obviously it's not in the user's interest to let apps know you're using a VPN, and I don't see a reason why apps should have access to check network settings on OS level.

Comment: Read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/249703/can-app-service-provider-konw-when-its-user-using-selfhost-vpn-server) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102283/can-a-wifi-access-point-operator-tell-that-im-streaming-video-to-my-phone/102285) to understand how streaming services detect use of VPN //you can use VPN servers that allow streaming and take remedies to prevent detection (not sure how effective it is though VPN Unlimited, which I use claims this as a big plus)

Comment: [Check if a VPN connection is active in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28386553/9165920)

Comment: Even if OS doesn't let the apps know that their traffic is going through a VPN, it's hardly possible to hide this fact from a determined app developer.